# How to POST User Credential to external domain?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing web programming and have some trouble in implementing **log in to external domain**.

What I'm building is a web application that helps a user to log in to multiple domain from my site (mysite.com).
This is how my web application works.

1. My site(mysite.com) contains users's credential (ID and password) of other domains
2. When user logs in to my site(mysite.com), user's credentials are given from server
3. By clicking on the icons of the domain (ex. thenounproject.com), domain is open on a new tab with users logged in

To implement this, I investigated and checked many options, but I still gets error.

1. Posting the credential form to external domain

   ```html
   <form method="POST" action="https://thenounproject.com/accounts/login/" target="_blank">
      <input type="text" name="login" required>
      <input type="password" name="password" required>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
   </form>
   ```

The url(https://thenounproject.com/accounts/login/) is the login page of the domain(https://thenounproject.com/), and the name of the input (login / password) is same as the name of parameters that url POSTS to its own domain server.

But I got HTTP 403 Error, so it didn't work out.

2. Embedding credential into url (HTTP GET)

```html
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('https://username:password@thenounproject.com/accounts/login/')">
```

But above code also doesn't work, it just opens the url (https://thenounproject.com/accounts/login/) and log in doesn't work.

Would there be any way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a quick look at this for the noun project, they're using a CSRF token during log in.  These are designed to prevent you from doing exactly what you've described.  If you don't know what these are and why they're important, it's important you read up on them for your project before you continue

https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf

To make this work as described you would need something which can manipulate the browser's cookie store (like develop a custom browser extension).  You first need to establish a session to get the token (a GET to the login page should render this).  To work as described, you then need to have it added to the cookies in the browser for noun project's domain and this is actively prevented by a browser due to the security risk it introduces.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn't know the concept of the CSRF Token.. 
I wonder if adding CORS header would solve my problem
Otherwise, I would have to change my development method from pure webpage to browser extension.. etc